# Custom Permission Group for Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-permission-level

In a modern SharePoint Team site, I intended to create multiple permission groups or name lists based on department and type of access, then set specific documents library only allows specific SharePoint permission group or name list. Can I do that? And, how?

This will help me just update the members from permission group or name list, instead of going to each document library to update member. And, I have no access to Delve.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create different permission levels based on your requirements.
Each permission level can be assigned to any number of groups in the list and that way you can manage what permission a group is supposed to have in a document library or list.

It will be easy for you to manage users too as you will have a list which permission level a certain group has

Comment: Hi, am I able to put permission group under document library? Not by individual's name, but via permission group.

Answer (score 0):

Here're steps:

1.Create different groups with different permissions in the site permissions settings.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/customize-sharepoint-site-permissions

2.Set unique permissions in specific documents libraries.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-permissions-for-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782

Comment: when new hire onboard to a new department, is there a simple way for me to update only one place, instead of change the permission document library by documenet library? thanks.